# I want to use a calculated field as a constant reference value, but it keep changing with the filter

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I have a column `Sales` and a column `date`, I want to use the average sales from month 10 (October)  as reference to compare with the others months.

I made a calculated field `Sales_december` like `avgIf(Sales,date<parseDate('10/31/2022','MM/dd/yyyy'))`

- *10/01/2022 is the first date in the `date` column
- I'm using `Sales_december` as a reference line in a line chart, every time I filter the date to a specific month `Sales_december` goes to zero. The only solution I found was to create a field `Sales_december_const` with the average value of `Sales_december`, Ex.:  `Sales_december_const =2000`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

avgOver(ifelse({date} < parseDate('10/31/2022', 'MM/dd/yyyy'), {sales}, NULL), [], PRE_FILTER)

You need to use PRE_FILTER in this position to avoid the filters affecting the value.

PRE_FILTER and PRE_AGG are not supported with avgif, but using ifelse here should work how you have it set up in your calculation.

Comment: Please provide snippet of running code.